# javascript regex pattern with an array

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a regex pattern which should be able to search through an array.

Let's say :

```
var arr = [ "first", "second", "third" ];

var match = text.match(/<arr>/);
```

which should be able to match only

```
<first> or <second> or <third> ......
```

but should ignore

`<ffirst> or <dummy>`

I need an efficient approach please .

Any help would be great .
Thanks

Comment: I want to match tags which are enclosed within angular brackets and highlight them but the text inside brackets should be in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should search for a specific word from a list using `(a|b|c)`.

The list is made from the `arr` by joining the values with `|` char as glue

```
var arr = [ "first", "second", "third" ];

var match = text.match(new RegExp("<(?:"+arr.join("|")+")>")); //matches <first> <second> and <third>
```

Note that if your "source" words might contain regular expression's preserved characters - you might get into trouble - so you might need to escape those characters before joining the array

A good function for doing so can be found [here](http://phpjs.org/functions/preg_quote/):

```
function regexpQuote(str, delimiter) {
  return String(str)
    .replace(new RegExp('[.\\\\+*?\\[\\^\\]$(){}=!<>|:\\' + (delimiter || '') + '-]', 'g'), '\\$&');
}
```

so in this case you'll have

```
function escapeArray(arr){
    var escaped = [];
    for(var i in arr){
       escaped.push(regexpQuote(arr[i]));
    }
    return escaped;
}

var arr = [ "first", "second", "third" ];
var pattern = new RegExp("<(?:"+escapeArray(arr).join("|")+")>");
var match = text.match(pattern); //matches <first> <second> and <third>
```

Comment: Don't forget to ensure `arr` isn't containing `|` and similar functional characters before compiling this way.

Answer (score 4):

1. First you can do [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to quote all special regex characters.
2. Then you can do [array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join the array elements using `|` and create an instance of `RegExp`.

#### Code:

```
function quoteSpecial(str) { return str.replace(/([\[\]^$|()\\+*?{}=!.])/g, '\\$1'); }

var arr = [ "first", "second", "third", "fo|ur" ];
var re = new RegExp('<(?:' + arr.map(quoteSpecial).join('|') + ')>');
//=> /<(?:first|second|third|fo\|ur)>/
```

then use this `RegExp` object:

```
'<first>'.match(re); // ["<first>"]

'<ffirst>'.match(re); // null

'<dummy>'.match(re); // null

'<second>'.match(re); // ["<second>"]

'<fo|ur>'.match(re); // ["<fo|ur>"]
```

Comment: You're welcome, and a great question +1. And sorry I got a call in between to could not submit desired edit in time.